# How can I get my output working for the default dictionary of lists

Tags: python

```
ls1 = [['b', (1, 1)], ['b', (1, 2)], ['b', (1, 3)], ['c', (2, 1)], ['c', (2, 2)]]
ls2 = ['A', 'B']

from itertools import groupby

key = lambda x: x[1][0]
lens = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(ls1, key=key), key=key)]
dct = dict(zip(ls2, lens))
```

my output comes as

```
{'A': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Instead of using dict in the last line of the code if I use

```
d2 = defaultdict(list)
```

then how can I get the same output in d2

Comment: `zip` discards all data that cannot be matched to another

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will get much benefit from using a defaultdict for this, but here is a version that uses collections.Counter:

```
ls1 = [['b', (1, 1)], ['b', (1, 2)], ['b', (1, 3)], ['c', (2, 1)], ['c', (2, 2)]]
ls2 = ['A', 'B']

from collections import Counter

lens = Counter(x[1][0] for x in ls1)
d2 = dict((k, v[1]) for k, v in zip(ls2, sorted(lens.items())))
```

A slightly shorter but potentially more confusing alternative for the last line:

```
d2 = dict(zip(ls2, zip(*sorted(lens.items()))[1]))
```